# Unbiased estimator in Laplace distribution

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

If $X\sim f_X(x\mid\theta)=\frac{1}{2\theta}e^{-|x|/\theta}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\theta>0,$ find an unbiased estimator of $(1+\theta)^{-1}$ of least variation.

I have tried using the fact that $|X|\sim \exp(1/\theta)$ and so $T=\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i| \sim \operatorname{gamma}(n,1/\theta)$ . I calculate that $E[1/T]=\frac{1}{(n-1)\theta}$ but I can't calculate something like $E[1/(1+T)]$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I see you are new. This question would be answered faster if you would show us what you have tried. What do you know already, etc? The question as it is stated right now is like you are giving us a homework exercise. Read your own question again. How does it feel? There are  people that are willing to do 99 kinds of helping on this site, but doing somebodies else homework ain't one.

Comment: I have tried using the fact that $|X|\sim exp(1/\theta)$ and so $T=\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i| \sim gamma(n,1/\theta)$ . I calculate that $E[1/T]=\frac{1}{(n-1)\theta}$ but I can't calcualte something like $E[1/(1+T)]$ ..

Comment: I would advice you to add that to your question since your question has the risk to being closed. Add details to let people know that you have tried to solve it yourself before posting it here, you know what I mean? You know how to edit your question, right?

Comment: ok question edited

Comment: If you can find a function $g(X_1)$ of the first observation $X_1$ for which $\operatorname E(g(X_1)) = 1/(1+\theta)$ (and which function $g$ is, is not allowed to depend on $\theta$), then the conditional expected value $\operatorname E(g(X) \mid\,\, |X_1| + \cdots + |X_n|)$ should be your minimum-variance unbiased estimator.